# Two limit questions involving radicals

Tags: calculus, limits

Hello can anyone help me solve the following limits?

$$\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{\sqrt{x^2+1}-2}{\sqrt{x-1}} \tag{1}$$

$$\lim_{x\to 1} \frac{x^2+1}{\sqrt{2x+2} - 2} \tag{2}$$

The radicals are kind of confusing me I am unsure how to deal with them.

Comment: What have you tried? What do you know? Are you allowed to apply L'Hopital? Do you know how to multiply by a conjugate?

Comment: I fixed the LaTeX in your post. If I misinterpreted (miswrote) one or both of your limits, let me know and I'll fix it.

Comment: @Joe: I’m pretty sure that you misinterpreted the first limit, though you correctly transcribed what was actually written; I’ve changed it the one that I think was intended. It’s to be hoped that Fernando will let us know, though.

Comment: first limit is $-\infty$ and second is $+\infty$

Comment: The original of (1) involved $(\sqrt{x^2+1}-\sqrt2)/(x-1)$, which is very different from what's there now.

Comment: yes it is minus square root of 2.

Comment: be couse the nominator and denominator both have a limit of zero as x tend to a is called indeterminate form of 0/0. ##

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the edit history, I'm going to assume (1) is supposed to be $$\lim_{x\to1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}-\sqrt2\over x-1}$$ in which case (as Calvin Lin hints in a comment) your first step is to multiply top and bottom by $\sqrt{x^2+1}+\sqrt2$. After you do that, if you need more help, show us what you got, we'll see what we can do.

For (2), I wonder whether that was supposed to be $x^2-1$ in the numerator.

Comment: I did the multiplication and I got ((x^2+1-2))/((x-1)square root(x^2+1)-square root(2))

Comment: Good. Now, what can you do with $x^2+1-2$? and, once you've done what you can do with $x^2+1-2$, what can you do with $(x^2+1-2)/(x-1)$? By the way, if you're going to make regular use of this website, it will be well worth your while to learn a little about formatting mathematics here. The faq will get you started.

Answer (score 2):

This exercise seem me "bad-looking" but...
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow1^{-}}\frac{\sqrt{x^2+1}-2}{\sqrt{x-1}}=i\infty$$
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow1^{+}}\frac{\sqrt{x^2+1}-2}{\sqrt{x-1}}=\infty$$
so two-sided limit does not exist.
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow1^{-}}\frac{x^2+1}{\sqrt{2x+2}-2}=-\infty$$
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow1^{+}}\frac{x^2+1}{\sqrt{2x+2}-2}=\infty$$
so two-sided limit does not exist.